# Changing const primitive only generating warning

Tags: c, constants, standards

I'm using Dev-C++ v4.9.8.0 and I wrote the lines

```
const int i = 512;
i = 200;
```

and when I went to compile, I expected to see a compile-time error, but only got a warning. I told Dev-C++ that I want to compile this into a C program. My compiler under the hood is MinGW gcc v2.95, all of this running on a Windows 7 machine. I thought it was a language standard to generate a compile-time error when a program attempts to change a value declared with the `const` qualifier. Does the standard say this only warrants a warning?

Here's my program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  const int i = 512;
  i = 250;

  system("PAUSE");  
  return 0;
}
```

And here's the Compile Log:

7 C:\C_Programs\Practice\main.c
[Warning] assignment of read-only variable `i'

Comment: gcc 2.95 is _ancient_.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: Wow, you're right; 13 years: http://gcc.gnu.org/releases.html

Comment: Am now using v4.5.2 (see comments in James McNellis's answer) still only getting warning and wondering if that's standard.

Comment: Post a complete program that demonstrates the problem, and the command that you use to invoke the compiler, and the exact output that the compiler gives.

Comment: Added program and output. Used Dev-C++ toolbar button to compile. Dev-C++ is calling gcc v4.5.2

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"Does the standard say this only warrants a warning?"*

The standard make no distinction of warnings and errors. The standard only has diagnostic messages.

```
const int i = 512;
i = 200;
```

In this program, there is a constraint violation of the assignment operator. The implementation has to issue a diagnostic message. The compiler is then free to continue to translate this program. But a program with a constraint violation is not a C program.

Answer (score 3):

gcc 2.95 is *ancient*.  It has many bugs that have been fixed in more recent versions.

Your best bet is to upgrade to a newer version of gcc.

Comment: Thanks. I just noticed that while I do have gcc and g++ v4.5.2 on my computer, the gcc and g++ Dev-C++ is using (I got this Dev-C++ with a book at Goodwill) is the 2.9.5 version) Working on changing the settings now.

Comment: Changed my compiler settings in Dev-C++ to actually use the 4.5.2 compiler, still not getting errors, only warning.